# SSL error on web request when using CNAME

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl

How do you fix an SSL error caused by a CNAME DNS record?

I have an API hosted on AWS accessible from a URL like https://sd098fs0f98s9f0s.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

To shorten this and rebrand it a little, I setup a CNAME record to map myapi.mydomain.com to sd098fs0f98s9f0s.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

Using the original URL, this simple Python is able to access the API perfectly:

```
import requests     
r = requests.get(url='https://sd098fs0f98s9f0s.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com')
```

However, using the new URL:

```
import requests     
r = requests.get(url='https://myapi.mydomain.com')
```

results in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File ".env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File ".env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File ".env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 370, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File ".env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 355, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)
```

What's causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you're using https. The server certificate is issued to specific hostname (Common name attribute). This name has to match the address you're trying to access with HTTPS. If you added DNS CNAME you have to update the certificate. If I recall correctly you have to add CNAME as Alternative Subject Name attribute, so you'll need a new certificate.

The error "WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER" might be somewhat misleading. It means that the server presented a wrong TLS version. In the TLS handshake, client and the server negotiate the TLS version. If the server supports only 1.0 and your client accept only 1.2+ then "WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER" will appear. But it might also happen if the client gets some unexpected data, like a **plain HTTP** instead of HTTPS. To check what exactly was the unexpected data, you'll have to capture wireshark / tcpdump network traffic logs. I wasted a lot of time debugging wrong_version_number recently. Only after looking at wireshark logs it became clear that it was the China firewall, because we got HTTP Forbidden to the initial Client Hello.